# Compare two nsdatecomponent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

if I have two nsdatecomponent and I want a know if the TIME in the first object is bigger than the second.

example:

```
if (nsdatecomponentObject1 > nsdatecomponentObject2)
{
    //something
}
```

Because this way don't works, how I can do this?

Comment: What does it mean to compare the two NSDateComponents of the same month, day, and year if one has a weekday specified and the other does not?  Where are these rules specified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `compare:` on the [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the `NSDateComponent`.

```
if([[nsdatecomponentObject1 date] compare:[nsdatecomponentObject2 date]] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

Comment: Note for Mac developers: This method only exists in the iOS version of Foundation (so far, anyway — it will probably be in Lion).

Comment: the result of my comparaison is always 0, why?

Comment: I think your answer only compare the date, because my thow nsdateobjects haves the same date but not the same "seconde component", and the result is nsorderedsame.

Comment: In my case, [nsdatecomponentObject1 date] is returning 0 always.

Comment: I believe the `date` method will only return a date if the `calendar` property is not `nil`. Calling the `compare:` method on `nil` returns `0`, which maps to `NSOrderedSame`.

Answer (score 1):

The right (and only) way to compare "on-the-fly" two NSDateComponents, is to use an NSCalendar object:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

switch([[gregorian dateFromComponents:oneNSDateComponents] compare:[gregorian dateFromComponents:anotherNSDateComponents]]) {
    case NSOrderedSame:
        NSLog(@"orderSame");
        break;
    case  NSOrderedAscending:
        NSLog(@"orderAscending");
        break;
    case  NSOrderedDescending:
        NSLog(@"orderDescending");
        break;
}
```